# Ball drawing problem with a condition (with replacing and without replacing)

Tags: statistics, conditional-probability

You have $9$ balls in a bag: $4$ blue, $2$ purple, $3$ green. If you draw $3$ balls and I tell you that you've drawn at least $1$ blue, what is the probability that you've drawn $3$ blue balls?

- solve for both, replacing and not replacing the balls.

My attempts so far: using Bayes' rule we get $P(3\ blue | al1\ blue) = \frac{P(al1\ blue | 3\ blue) \cdot P(3\ blue)}{P(al1\ blue)}$, here "$al1$" is "at least one."

Hence, without replacing I get: $$P(3\ blue | al1 \, blue) = \frac{1 \cdot \left(\frac{4}{9} \cdot \frac{3}{8} \cdot\frac{2}{7}\right)}{\left(1-all\ non\ blue\right)}=\frac{1 \cdot \left(\frac{4}{9} \cdot \frac{3}{8} \cdot \frac{2}{7}\right)}{\left(1-\frac{5}{9} \cdot \frac{4}{8}\cdot\frac{3}{7}\right)}=\frac{2}{37}.$$
With replacing, the formula is the same but numerators and denominators don't decrease and we get $\dfrac{16}{151}$.

This doesn't feel right, what are more intuitive ways to
think about this problem and hence solve it?

As this doesn't feel right, I have tried taking another approach which feels much better yet I am not 100% sure: there are $3$ possibilities: the first, the second and the third ball was blue. In case of without replacing summing them up will be:

$$\frac{3\cdot2}{8\cdot7} + \frac{4\cdot2}{8\cdot7} + \frac{4\cdot3}{9\cdot8} = \frac{105}{252},$$
and in case of replacements, again, the approach is the same but numbers dont decrease

Comment: Could you edit what you have tried into the question?

Comment: @Henry added 2 of my approaches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative approach without replacement,

- there in a sense ${9 \choose 3} = 84$ equally likely ways of choosing three balls from nine
- ${4 \choose 3}=4$ are all blue
- ${5 \choose 3}=10$ are none blue
- $84-10=74$ have at least one blue

so the conditional probability you want has probability $\frac{4}{74}=\frac{2}{37}$ as you found.

With replacement,

- there in a sense $9^3 = 729$ equally likely ways of choosing the three balls from nine
- $4^3=64$ are all blue
- $5^3=125$ are none blue
- $729-125=604$ have at least one blue

so the conditional probability you want has probability $\frac{64}{604}=\frac{16}{151}$ as you also found.

Comment: the reason why I am concerned here is because these probabilities seems too small, there is another approach by looking at probability spaces, this is the original question I had: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4359820/ball-drawing-problem-with-a-condition-without-replacing

Comment: Getting three blue balls in three draws is unlikely (about $0.048$ without replacement and about $0.088$ with replacement) while the probability of at least one blue is high (about $0.88$ without replacement and about $0.83$ with replacement) so you might reasonably thing the conditional probabilities will also be small