# Ball drawing problem with a condition without replacing

Tags: combinatorics, statistics, conditional-probability

You have 4 balls in a bag, 2 yellow, 1 black, 1 red. If you drawn 2 balls I tell you that at least 1 is yellow, what is the probability that you've drawn 2 yellow balls?

There are two ways I see that this can be solved: using Bayes formula and looking at the probability space.

Using Bayes formula we get $P(2\ yellow | al1\ yellow) = \frac{P(al1\ yellow | 2\ yellow) \cdot P(2\ yellow)}{P(al1\ yellow)}$, here "$al1$" us at lease one.

Hence we get
$$P(2\ yellow | al1 \, blue) = \frac{1 \cdot \left(\frac{2}{4} \cdot \frac{1}{3}\right)}{\left(1-all\ non\ yellow\right)}=\frac{1 \cdot \left(\frac{2}{4} \cdot \frac{1}{3} \right)}{\left(1-\frac{2}{4} \cdot \frac{1}{3}\right)}=\frac{1}{5}.$$

Using probability space approach we get these possible combinations: YY,YB, YR, RY, BY hence the probability of 2 yellows is 1/5

Now the above solutions only work in case we draw balls in order, if we draw them simultaneously the solution is different and from probability space we get the answer of 1/3

Please explain what solution is correct and why

Comment: It does not concern Bayes rule. If $Y$ stand for number of yellow balls then:$$P(Y=2|Y>0)=\frac{P(Y=2)}{P(Y>0)}$$where numerator and denominator are not difficult to find. Also drawing one by one does not differ essentially from drawing simultaneously.

Comment: can you please explain why it does not concern Bayes rule?

Comment: Bayes rule comes in if you are asked to find a conditional probability $P(A|B)$ that is at first sight difficult while at the same time it is easy to find $P(B|A)$. In that case we can use the rule which boils down to exploiting the handsome equality:$$P(A|B)P(B)=P(B|A)P(A)$$ But here you are not in such a situation. It is not difficult to find $P(Y=2|Y>0)$ directly.

Comment: right, I just dont understand how to do this exactly, I found 2 ways of doing this and tbh I am not convinced which one is the correct one

Comment: First, the problem is phrased such that we draw the balls simultaneously.  If you draw them in order you should include things like $YR$ and $RY$ both as being scenarios where you drew at least one yellow ball.  Second, the balls themselves are distinct objects that occupy different positions in space, even if we can't tell the difference between them by sight.  You should think of it as ball Yellow1 and ball Yellow2.  So, we really have both $Y_1R$ and $RY_1$ *as well as* outcomes $Y_2R$ and $RY_2$.

Comment: As for "If we draw them simultaneously we get 1/3" No, you don't.  Recall that there are two outcomes to playing the lottery.  You win or you lose.  You do not win the lottery with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ however.  Some of these outcomes are more likely to occur than others.  You can only use counting techniques like that in equiprobable sample spaces, which is what reimagining the problem such that the balls are labeled by different numbers allows us to do.

Comment: Your first solution is wrong (see answer of Math Lover) and your solution using probability space is correct. Also $1/3$ is wrong. This because the $3$ solutions that you have in mind there are not equiprobable.

Comment: With regards to your first shown attempt, you used $\frac{2}{4}\cdot \frac{1}{\color{red}{4}}$, which would have been correct if we were drawing *with replacement*, however it is heavily implied that we are not.  Similarly for the denominator.  After having drawn a ball there are fewer balls remaining to draw from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first approach, your mistake is in the calculation of $P(Y=2)$ and $P(Y \geq 1)$.

$ \displaystyle P(Y = 2) = \frac 2 4 \cdot \frac 1 3 = \frac 16$

$ \displaystyle P(Y \geq 1) = 1 - P(Y = 0) = 1 - \frac 24 \cdot \frac 1 3 = \frac 56$

So, $ \displaystyle ~P(Y = 2 \mid Y \geq 1) = \frac 1 5$

If we were drawing simultaneously,

$ \displaystyle P(Y = 2) = {2 \choose 2} / {4 \choose 2} = \frac 16$

$ \displaystyle P(Y \geq 1) = 1 - P(Y = 0) = 1 - {2 \choose 2} / {4 \choose 2} = \frac 56$

That gives the same answer.

While your second approach gives correct answer, you should be careful in how you write the reduced sample space. You need to consider each ball different to make sure the outcomes in the sample space are equally probable. So it is in fact,

$\{Y ~y\}, \{y ~Y\}, \{Y ~B\}, \{y ~B\}, \{B ~Y\}, \{B ~y\}, \{Y ~R\}, \{y ~R\}, \{R ~Y\}, \{R ~y\}$

and that gives probability of $\dfrac 2{10}$.

Comment: To make things more complete as answer I suggest to add an explanation why $1/3$ is wrong.

Comment: @drhab thanks. I added more details.